# Should I use a "row" class as the basis of a grid in Foundation 6 CSS Framework

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LSOmVsmeJU) advocates the use of a

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

as the basis for building a foundation grid, however the examples [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) make no reference to it.

What is the correct approach in Foundation 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of them. XY-grid is an alternative for row-cols grid.

XY-grid is more advanced and has more features but is not supported in older browsers. As from docs:

> The XY grid is supported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari 6+, IE10+, iOS 7+,
>   and Android 4.4+.

To ensure maximum compatibility use row-cols grid.

Answer (score -1):

I think, You should XY-grid. Because, Zurb doesn't support 'Float Grid' in version 7.